# Counting adverbs using re module

Tags: python, python-3.x

Count the adverbs in a given string using `re.findall()` in python. Adverb is any word which ends with `"ly"`. Words with `"ly"` (e.g. "flying") except the last 2 characters are not to be counted

```
def count_adverbs(text):

    advbs = re.findall(r"\w+ly", text)
    if advbs:
        return len(advbs)
    else:
        return 0
```

For example i have these 2 strings

```
a = "flying"
b = "i clearly i lying lonely"
```

`print(count_adverbs(a))` gives 1 but it should be 0 because `"ly"` should be counted only if it is at the end of the string
`print(count_adverbs(b))` works fine. It gives 2

Comment: Adding a word boundary might help: `r"\w+ly\b"`

Comment: 'Adverb is any word which ends with `"ly"`'—not really true, but maybe you're willing to accept false positives like "fly` for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a word boundary in your regex using `\b`, so your regex will change to `\b\w+ly\b` and it ensures `ly` falls at the end of the word

You can also simplify your return statement by checking for the length of `advbs` in a ternary operator

```
import re
def count_adverbs(text):

    advbs = re.findall(r"\b\w+ly\b", text)

    #Return length if advbs are non-empty, else return 0
    return len(advbs) if advbs else 0

print(count_adverbs("flying"))
print(count_adverbs("i clearly i lying lonely"))
print(count_adverbs("ly ly"))
```

The output will be

```
0
2
0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\b` token to indicate word boundary:

```
\w+ly\b
```

But you don't Regex here, **string manipulation with `split` and `endswith` would suffice** and should be faster than Regex:

```
In [207]: [word for word in b.split() if word.endswith('ly')]                                                                                                                                               
Out[207]: ['clearly', 'lonely']

In [208]: re.findall(r'\w+ly\b', b)                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[208]: ['clearly', 'lonely']
```

Timings:

```
In [209]: %timeit [word for word in b.split() if word.endswith('ly')]                                                                                                                                       
1.37 µs ± 13.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [210]: %timeit re.findall(r'\w+ly\b', b)                                                                                                                                                                 
2.27 µs ± 106 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I also fell into Regex trap quite often. Now I think (harder) for finding a *string way* before moving to Regex.